# WSO2 API Response With Connection #0 to host localhost left intact

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I am unable to read all the response form device-mgt api in between the response. I have the error stating "Connection #0 to host localhost left intact". Can you please help me to fix ?

**Sample Response:**

`{"id":98,"dateOfEnrolment":1517461050248,"dateOfLastUpdate":1517461050248,"ownership":"BYOD","status":"ACTIVE","owner":"admin"}},{"id":99,"name":"003","type":"camera","description":"003","deviceIdentifier":"003","enrolmentInfo":{"id":99,"dateOfEnrolment":1517461108463,"dateOfLastUpdate":1517461108463,"ownership":"BYOD","status":"ACTIVE","owner":"admin"}},**{"id":100,"n* Connection #0 to host 192.168.1.18 left intact**
ame":"004","type":"camera","description":"004","deviceIdentifier":"004","enrolmentInfo":{"id":100,"dateOfEnrolment":1517461156563,"dateOfLastUpdate":1517461156563,"ownership":"BYOD","status":"ACTIVE","owner":"admin"}},{"id":101,"name":"005","type":"camera","description":"005","deviceIdentifier":"005","enrolmentInfo":{"id":101,"dateOfEnrolment":1517461200437,"dateOfLastUpdate":1517461200437,"ownership":"BYOD","status":"ACTIVE","owner":"admin"}}]`

Comment: How do you invoke this api? using CURL commands? . Let us know the command you trying.

Comment: Are using the curl to do the request? Can you please use a POSTMAN or a REST Client to do the request?

Comment: I am using the postman

Comment: The response count is 39. But, I am getting only 20 response.

Comment: Provided information is not sufficient. Are you getting this error through the HTTP response? Can you see any errors in the command console? Please add the API call you are trying to question.

Comment: https://192.168.1.18:8243/api/device-mgt/v1.0/devices
I do not get any error in the console. The same curl command
**curl -v -k -X GET -H 'authorization: Bearer 41871ba0-3f12-3deb-a253-3911712a8187' 'https://192.168.1.18:8243/api/device-mgt/v1.0/devices'**

Comment: Put essential info in the question, not comments.

Answer (score 0):

Seems your CURL command is incorrect.

**Solution:**

Please try below command;

```
curl -k -X GET 'https://192.168.1.18:8243/api/device-mgt/v1.0/devices?offset=0&limit=100' -H 'authorization: Bearer 41871ba0-3f12-3deb-a253-3911712a8187'
```

**Explanation:**

As per the CURL command; you are trying the port 8243. Port 8243 is HTTPS. Thus you need to specify the protocol as `https://192.168.1.18:8243`. You may also use port 8280 for HTTP communication.

**Edit:**
You need to add `https://` before the host name address of the API call. Please refer above API call carefully. And please refer [this docs](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS310/swagger/?url=https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS310/swagger/device-mgt.json#!/Device_Management/getDevices) for offset and limit parameters. You can query devices in a paginated way with the **offset** and **limit** parameters.

Comment: How to fix it in REST Client?. what is the meaning for **offset=0&limit=100** ?

Comment: Please add 'https://' into front of the hostname of your REST client. `offset` and `limit` are well-known query parameters for the paginated REST APIs. Please refer https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS310/swagger/?url=https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS310/swagger/device-mgt.json#!/Device_Management/getDevices

Comment: is it  not possible to get all the device without using offset and limit? If i have more than 1000 device. How do i need to work with offset and limit.

Comment: You cannot fetch all devices at once; this has implemented to avoid heavy load on the server. You can do the following;

[1]. Fetch devices with the offset=0 and limit=1.
[2]. Parse the response and get device count(device count here is all devices count).
[3]. Fetch devices with the offset=0 and limit=<device_count>

Comment: Thank You So Much. If have device count more than 100. I have this issue.
{
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request parameter limit should be less than or equal to 100.",
    "errorItems": []
}

Comment: Glad I could help you there. Your last query is not related to the original question, please go ahead and create a new question for your query. And if I answered to your question; please mark this as the answer.